# How to get grand total without shipping costs from a Magento order?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to implement and get some affiliate calculation from success.phtml page. Everything is working well except 'bd' which should be grand total without shipping cost. I might missing something in 'bd' code. I am new to php code. Please help me out regarding this problem! [Please look into screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snInM.jpg)

```
<?php
// Add this to the file in the following path: app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/success.phtml
$iProgramId = 9560; // Insert your Program ID here

// Add the matching domain here. 
$sMatchingDomain = 'https://dt51.net'; //For example: ds1.nl or dt51.net


// Retrieve order details and billing address
$oOrderDetails = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$aBillingAddressData = $oOrderDetails->getBillingAddress();
$amount = $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getShippingAmount();


foreach ($oOrderDetails->getAllItems() as $oItem) 
{
     break;
}

$aVariables = array(
    'si' => $iProgramId,
    'ti' => $this->getOrderId(),
    'oa' => substr($oItem->getName(), 0, 50),
    'om' => substr($oItem->getName(), 0, 50),
    'bd' => number_format($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal - $oOrderDetails->getShippingAmount(), 2, '.', ''),
    'ln' => $aBillingAddressData['country_id'],
    'pc' => $aBillingAddressData['postcode'],
    'rv' => number_format($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', ''),
    'e1' => $oOrderDetails->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(),
    'e2' => $oItem->getSku(),
    'e3' => round($oItem->getQtyOrdered(), 0)
);
$sUrl = "".$sMatchingDomain."/t/";
$sGlue = "?";

foreach ($aVariables as $sKey => $mValue)
{
    $sUrl .= $sGlue.$sKey."=".urlencode($mValue);
    $sGlue = "&";
} 

echo '<img src="'.$sUrl.'" style="border: 0px; height: 1px; width: 1px;" alt="Affiliate Marketing" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have did a mistake in the following line.  `getGrandTotal()`

```
'bd' => number_format($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal - $oOrderDetails->getShippingAmount(), 2, '.', '')
```

Replace with this

```
'bd' => number_format($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal() - $oOrderDetails->getShippingAmount(), 2, '.', ''),
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I have corrected with your code but still no luck. Its not calculating grand total without shipping cost. with getSubtotal() i can get price excluding tax, with getGrandTotal() i can get Grand Total, but i am not getting grand total without shipping cost with ($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal() - $oOrderDetails->getShippingAmount(), 2, '.', ''),

Comment: Did you get any value in shipping amount?

Comment: no i do not get any value of shipping amount. It is a flat rate of 6.90 Euro. Is it possible to get 'bd' value like below 'bd' => number_format($oOrderDetails->getGrandTotal() - 6.90

Comment: anyone have the solution ?